# What is the animated style on the new imac pro page called?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a webpage that replcates the animation that takes place on the apple imac pro page.

What is this type of animation called?
Can this be done using HTML5 and CSS3 only?

https://www.apple.com/uk/imac-pro/?afid=p238%7CsQ4bjRw3L-dc_mtid_20925wi539930_pcrid_198758187038_&cid=wwa-uk-kwgo-mac-bran-imac+pro-e-slid--productid-

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source?

Comment: yes but I need to know if this type of animation has a name so I can then do some more research. I cannot see in the source if the animation is done in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

The top of the site looks like Image sprites (you can also do something similar with playing a video when you scroll) 
see this: https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc/

```
function scrollPlay(){  
  var frameNumber  = window.pageYOffset/playbackConst;
  vid.currentTime  = frameNumber;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
```

I had to add some of the code so I could post the codepen link above...

The rest of the site "style" is similar to parallax scrolling see these:
https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/
https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/